# Using Angular $scope variable inside an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I tried searching SO for similar question as mine, but could not get any. Pardon if this question is duplicate and has already been answered.

My HTML has two input fields for First Name and Last Name, and a button:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="fname"/>
     <input type="text" ng-model="lname"/>
     <input type="button" ng-click="createObj();" value="Clear Scope"/>
     <p>Fname = {{fname}}</p>
     <p>Lname = {{lname}}</p>
 </div>
```

This is my JS file which has the controller function:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

   $scope.fname = "sandeep";
   $scope.lname = "nayak";

   $scope.createObj= function(){

     var obj = {fn:$scope.fname, ln: $scope.lname};
     console.log(obj);

     $scope.fname = "";
     $scope.lname = "";

     console.log(obj);

   };


});
```

In `createObj` method, I create an object which holds the first name and last name, and then I clear the $scope.

I log the object twice, before and after I clear the $scope. But I do not see any difference.

Why is the object still same, even after I clear the $scope, since I refer the $scope in my object?

http://jsfiddle.net/7eo4zcvq/

Comment: You are not referring the scope in the object, you are assigning a property from scope on to your object (which is pass by value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not related to Angular but simply to Javascript itself.

When you write

```
var obj = {fn:$scope.fname, ln: $scope.lname};
```

$scope.fname/lname are resolved into their value, which are strings, so this object happens to be in fact initialized to

```
var obj = {fn:"sandeep", ln:"nayak"};
```

So clearing the scope won't have any effect on it: that is because strings are not treated like regular objects but like native types (same as numbers and boolean).

A simpler example of this behavior is that:

```
var a = "hello";
var b = a;
a = "world";
console.log(a);       // outputs "world"
console.log(b);       // outputs "hello"
console.log(a === b); // outputs false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the variable obj again with the new values of fname and lname. Clearing the values of fname and lname won't have any effect on obj. Kindly see updated code below.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.fname = "sandeep";
    $scope.lname = "nayak";

    $scope.createObj = function(){
        var obj = {fn:$scope.fname, ln: $scope.lname};
        console.log(obj);

        $scope.fname = "";
        $scope.lname = "";
        var obj = {fn:$scope.fname, ln: $scope.lname};

        console.log(obj);
    }



});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the value of `obj` after clearing the scope; you will have to either manually update the `obj` as suggested by @Joshua Arvin Lat or you may like to convert the `fn` and `ln` to functions:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.fname = "sandeep";
$scope.lname = "nayak";

$scope.createObj = function(){
    var obj = {fn:function() {return $scope.fname;} , ln: function() {return $scope.lname;} };
    console.log(obj.fn());
    console.log(obj.ln());    

    $scope.fname = "";
    $scope.lname = "";

    console.log(obj.fn());
    console.log(obj.ln());    

}
```

});

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7eo4zcvq/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to store the reference. Define an object in `$scope`, not a variable of primitive type.

```
$scope.person = {
    fname: "sandeep",
    lname: "nayak"
}

$scope.createObj = function(){
    var obj = {
        person: $scope.person,
        toString: function(){
            return this.person.fname + ' ' + this.person.lname;
        }};
    console.log(obj.toString());

    $scope.person.fname = "a";
    $scope.person.lname = "a";

    console.log(obj.toString());
}
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eo4zcvq/3/)